# Extract gz and convert csv to xlsx

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, gzip

I hope someone can help me with this issue. I tried to Google something that do what I need but there isn't any of specific or easy to adapt and I'm a dud with programming and coding...

An application I use everyday produces several gz files containing one csv file each. With the aim to simplify a bit my life I wish run a script that do this work:

1. Extract the csv files from any gz in the current folder
2. Save any extracted csv  file as xlsx files in the same folder
3. Rename the xlsx file properly
4. Delete any gz and csv files from the current folder

Here some more details about the environment and requirements:

- Running OS is Windows 7 Enterprise (Powershell is installed)
- Office 2010 is installed
- I can't install any additional software or library (it's a corporate laptop)
- Any csv file has the following naming convention:

  `CheeseFile_YellowCheese_yyyy_mm_dd-randomnumber_othersnumber.csv
  CheeseFile_BlueCheese_yyyy_mm_dd-randomnumber_othersnumber.csv
  HamFile_RawHam_yyyy_mm_dd-randomnumber_othersnumber.csv
  HamFile_CookedHam_yyyy_mm_dd-randomnumber_othersnumber.csv`
- And should be respectively saved as:

  `OutputFile - CheeseFile_mmddyyyy_Yellow Cheese.xlsx
  OutputFile - CheeseFile_mmddyyyy_Blue Cheese.xlsx
  OutputFile - HamFile_mmddyyyy_Raw Ham.xlsx
  OutputFile - HamFile_mmddyyyy_Coocked Ham.xlsx`
- The date in the original file name has to be kept in the output xlsx file
- Cheese files are in their folder and Ham files are in a separate folder so I can adapt the script as I need.

Please let me know if you need further details and thank you in advance for any appreciated help :)

Comment: 1. Google 'extract gz using powershell' 
2. Google 'convert csv to xlsx with powershell'
3. Google 'rename files with powershell'
4. Google 'delete files with powershell'

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired and in the 'right' mood for it but I'm guessing the OP actually spent more time placing this order than googling how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree the OP does not appear to have done their fair share of figuring this out (how hard is Google?), I know someone else will be looking in the future.  Posting information will help them.

@OP, I'm not going to do all your file handling work for you but here is the basic code to convert from CSV to XLSX which is probably the least common part of the question posed.

```
Option Explicit

Dim strCSVfile, strExcelFile, FSO
Dim objWorkbook, objWorksheet1

set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strCSVfile = "C:\temp\Excel Test\myFile.csv"
strExcelFile = "C:\temp\Excel Test\myFile.xlsb"  'this was changed

if FSO.FileExists(strCSVfile) then
   Dim objExcel
   Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

   objExcel.Visible = False
   objExcel.displayalerts=false

   'Import CSV into Spreadsheet
   Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.open(strCSVfile)
   Set objWorksheet1 = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

   'Save workbook (51 = 2010 format) 
   'Formats ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx
   'Parameters ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx 
   objWorksheet1.SaveAs strExcelFile, 50  'this was changed
   objExcel.Quit()
else
   msgbox "File Note found"
end if
```

**Edit:**  *BTW, OP@*... post your code and more people will help you.  If you update your question with the code you have written for unzipping and file handling, I will help with that part.

**Edit:**  Updated for .xlsb format output.  Lines changed marked as such.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Searching on Google I understood that probably the best language was PS but it's a real mess for me. For example during these days some requirement changed and now I've to save the files in xlsb. I followed the links you commented in the code hoping to find how update it by my self but I don't understand how to do it....

Answer (score -3):

```
7z e *.gz;ls | foreach {$old=$_.name;$newname='OutputFile - '+$oldname.split('_')[0]+'_'+$oldname.split('_')[3]+$oldname.split('_')[4]+$oldname.split('_')[2]+'_'+$oldname.split('_')[1]+'.xlsx';mv $oldname $newname }
```

Comment: That wouldn't produce a proper xlsx-file.